# Is there a data storage limit on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm working on something where I may need to move **more than 50 TB** of data from a MySQL database to **MongoDB Atlas on AWS**. I need to do a cost estimation before we can proceed. I'm not able to find good information to do the estimation.

**What did I try?**

- I have tried reading documentation, searching here and on Google but have not been able to find the answer.
- I also tried to create a cluster in Atlas on AWS and see if I can figure out some rough estimate on pricing, but the cluster creation UI tool does not give me the option to select more than 4 TB. Am I missing something?
- I have looked at posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327723/mongodb-limit-storage-size) but they are either old or did not address 50 TB.

Is there an easy way to figure this out? Or do you mind sharing some monthly billing round figure for per TB storage.

*(I do understand IOPS, backup etc cost extra.)*